# position div to the bottom

Tags: css

How can I get the content div to get at the bottom instead of that odd position?

http://jsfiddle.net/madprops/6FFXL/1/

```
<div>
 <div style='float:left'>name&nbsp;</div>
 <div style='float:left'>date&nbsp;</div>
 <div style='float:left'>comments&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div id="contenido" style="font-size:20px;">content</div>
```

EDIT: removed float:top

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to do. can you explain a little more what you want to end up with?

Comment: @Beno sorry I pasted the wrong jsfiddle I corrected the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is at the bottom for me in your example, (FF5), but you should probably make it safe by setting content to clear your floated divs, like this:

```
<div id="contenido" style="font-size:20px;clear:both;">content</div>
```

Also, the `float:top` on your first div is invalid, there is no `top` property of float.

Comment: that will do it :)  I'm using Chrome 12 btw